# Solr Search with wrong spell

Tags: solr, websolr

I have integrated Solr with My eComemrce web application. I am indexing product title and many other fields of Product to Solr. Now I have indexed **BLÅBÆRSOMMEREN** into product title/name. I have added EdgeNGram as well for Title field. Because of EdgeNGram if I search any of the token I got the result. And Because of spell check if I Search for wrong spell like: **BLÅBÆRISOMMEREN**, I got the result. But if I search for **BLÅBÆRI**, I did not get any result as there is not any token for the same.

I want the products in result which have **BLÅBÆR** because that token is exist. Same for any other wrong spell search.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to analyse by a specific field via UI solr  interface.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have Solr's tokenization configured differently for indexing and querying.

So, in your example the following terms may appear in the index:

- B
- BL
- BLÅ
- BLÅB
- BLÅBÆ
- BLÅBÆR
- BLÅBÆRS

However as your query terms are not being processed into ngrams, you are only *searching* for

- BLÅBÆRI

which does not appear within your indexed terms.

This is a common practice when using ngrams, however it sounds like in your use-case you want to return partial matches within your results.

Check your Solr schema to make sure that you have a matching EdgeNGram filter configured for query-time as you do for index-time, e.g.

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Make sure you're sorting by `score` though, as this strategy will most likely give you many false-positives!

Answer (score 1):

For misspelled words you can use a fuzzy query (allowing matches on index terms with an edit distance of ~1 or ~2 from the query term).

Using your example, **BLÅBÆRISOMMEREN** is edit distance 1 (one character difference) from your indexed term.

Therefore the query `q=title:BLÅBÆRISOMMEREN~1` will match your title term but **BLÅBÆRI** will not (without the ngram approach from the previous answer.).

You can also investigate Solr's [Suggester component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) if you're trying to build auto-suggest, as it also can handle fuzzy suggestions like: (BLÅBÆRI -> BLÅBÆRSOMMEREN)  and typically responds faster than a traditional query.

Comment: I have tried your solution in Solr dashboard, q=title:BLÅBÆRI~1 but it does not work.

Comment: I've updated my answer.   But for what you describe, the first answer (Toby Cole) is better suited.  Just make sure the EdgeNGram filter is applied to both query and index analysis as suggested, or this won't work for misspellings.  Also consider standard NGrams in place of EdgeNGrams to handle cases where the spelling mistake is **not** the last letter.

Comment: Thanks for you help.